# Implementing Typeahead on django

Tags: python, django, typeahead.js

I'm implementing typeahead for the first time and I'm doing something wrong in passing the URL here. This is my typeahead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var getIsbn = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: "/update/?q=%QUERY",
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });
    $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'isbn',
    display: 'value',
    source: getIsbn
  });
});
```

This is my `URL` in urls.py:

```
url(r'^update/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.update, name='update'),
```

When I open network panel **Page not found** is being displayed.
Any suggestion how to make this work?

Comment: Your URLs don't match. Typeahead is trying to access `/update/?q=whatever` but your urls.py has `/update/12345/`, which isn't the same at all. And why would typeahead - an autocomplete library - be calling a view called "update"?

Comment: then where should i point my typeahead url?

Comment: Erm, I don't know how to answer that question. You need a URL that matches what you have in the JS, and which returns data for typeahead to use.

Comment: i'm making an ajax request, to get pre-populated form. by any chance will I have to use the URL i'm using in ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure you know what typeahead *is*. Why are you using it? What do you think it does?

Comment: I'm using typeahead for the first time as i mentioned above that's why i'm facing an issue to implement it. All I know is i have to use typeahead. I want this typeahead to show all the ISBN number's present in the data base

Comment: Right. So you need a URL pointing to a view which returns those numbers in response to an Ajax request.

Comment: can show me  with the help of example?